# Are there any KL03 "arduinos"?

Tags: hardware

I have been trying to find any Arduino or similar prototyping board that uses this MCU

[image]

http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2453987,00.asp

But the smallest and more robust ones I have been able to find are Microduino and Espruino pico, none of which use this.

Are there any prototyping boards that use these?

Comment: I highly recommend searching the manufacturer's website: http://www.freescale.com/webapp/sps/site/prod_summary.jsp?code=FRDM-KL03Z&fsrch=1&sr=1&pageNum=1

Answer (score 1):

This development board uses a chip from the KL03 family:
http://www.freescale.com/webapp/sps/site/prod_summary.jsp?code=FRDM-KL03Z

However, as you can see, it uses the arduino uno form factor (like all their other freedom boards), so it's probably not what you were expecting with respect of size.

If you are looking for a dev board that you can prototype with (easy access to pins and all that) I doubt you can get anything significantly smaller than a teensy (https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/), which also uses a more powerful ARM M4 core. There has been quite a few kickstarters with tiny arduino-compatible boards, but I am not quite sure how many you can actually buy at the moment.